# Asp.net Core Log4net FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, log4net, log4net-configuration

I need to use log4net on a new Asp.net Core app. I get FileNotFoundException error when I run the project.

Startup.cs

ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddLogging(builder =>
{
    builder.AddConfiguration(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"))
           .AddConsole()
           .AddDebug();
 });
```

Configure Method:

```
   loggerFactory.AddLog4Net("log4net.config");
```

I get the error on this line.  Log4net.config file is in the UI project.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help. I've solved this problem. I changed the copy to output directory property for log4net.config file to copy always.

Comment: cual es lo que hiciste

Answer (score 0):

Could you change your configure method with this;

```
log4netConfig.Load(File.OpenRead("log4net.config"));
```